# Changing location of error log file

Tags: php

I want to change the location of the default log file, for example in php.ini:

```
error_log = /etc/var/php_error.log
```

Can I make this path absolute? And do I need to restart apache after doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you must restart server after changing path.

Comment: `/etc/var/php_error.log` is *already* an absolute path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you path start with `/` (for linux), that means its a absolute path. and as you making changes in configuration file of PHP, apache needs to be restarted when PHP is running as an Apache module.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it at runtime in your application by using:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_log', $yourAbsolutePath);
```